# Post value from PHP to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have one form in PHP, i want when i submit form, post input value to jQuery.
Actually when click on submit button, post "refresh-time" to jQuery.

I'm grateful for help

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload(); 
    }, $refresh-time);
</script>

<form method="POST">
   <label>refresh number</label>
   <input type="text" name="refresh-time">
   <button type="submit">apply</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Get the post value first, $refresh_time = $_POST["refresh-time"], then you should echo the variable, like <?=  $refresh_time ?>. validate the post var before getting it.

Comment: @Faiz99  Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you actually POSTing the form or purely using ajax/jquery without a page reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP can generate code javacript and html, and in php you can ECHO, PRINT all in your document, and IF you want give return value form php to java/jQuery is not problem

example:

```
<?php 
// this EXAMPLE POST, 
$time = $_POST['second'] * 1000; // convert milsec to sec
?>

<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
    // this place to use java code
    }, <?= $time; ?>); // use refresh variable 
</script>
```

i hope you understand, i recommend you for learning again for PHP (Sorry)

Comment: perfect,Thanks for your help @Abdul Aziz Al Basyir

Comment: for perfect, please give rate for this answer @fanasasharif

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
var refreshtime = <?= $_POST['refresh-time'] ?> || 10000;
    setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload(); 
    }, refreshtime);
</script>

<form method="POST">
   <label>refresh number</label>
   <input type="text" name="refresh-time">
   <button type="submit">apply</button>
</form>
```

i set 1000 as default value to use on first time. you have to read from $_POST array to access form submit values. then use tags echo to print on javascript code

Comment: your answer is concrete, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   //  refresh variable 
   $refresh_time = 1000;
?>

<script>
    setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload(); 
    }, <?= $refresh_time; ?>); // use refresh variable 
</script>

<form method="POST">
   <label>refresh number</label>
   <input type="text" name="refresh-time">
   <button type="submit">apply</button>
</form>
```